# Broken external HDD doesn't show up on devices list

Tags: usb, hard-drive, data-recovery, testdisk

my external hdd, got corrupted or damaged, not sure which one and I'm trying to fix it or at least get some data from it. (system damage of the hdd happened once already, but it was easily resolved by just logging on to linux and plugging in the device, I'm hoping for simmilar now, although the HDD is pretty old, meaning it might be hardware fault, but trying won't hurt) Couple weeks ago, HDD always showed "Format disk..." when plugged into Windows, but at least it showed something - now it doesn't show up on Windows and I can't find it on Linux either.

I've tried running `fdisk -l` command:

```
Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram1: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram2: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram3: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram4: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram5: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors                                                                   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes                                                                                    
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes                                                                   
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes                                                                      


Disk /dev/ram6: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors                                                                   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes                                                                                    
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes                                                                   
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes                                                                      


Disk /dev/ram7: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors                                                                   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes                                                                                    
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes                                                                   
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes                                                                      


Disk /dev/ram8: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors                                                                   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes                                                                                    
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes                                                                   
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes                                                                      


Disk /dev/ram9: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors                                                                   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes                                                                                    
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes                                                                   
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes                                                                      


Disk /dev/ram10: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors                                                                  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes                                                                                    
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes                                                                   
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes                                                                      


Disk /dev/ram11: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram12: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram13: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram14: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0ae012d9

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048 158662655 158660608 75.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2  *    158662656 234441647  75778992 36.1G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000649fc
```

Then I've tried to run `dmesg | tail -n 20` :

```
[  280.642286] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: JMicron
[  280.642287] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 00000011E09310C00197
[  280.651343] usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  280.651425] scsi host6: usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0
[  280.651459] scsi host6: runtime PM trying to activate child device host6 but parent (1-1.4:1.0) is not active
[  280.651510] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  280.652991] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  281.688894] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Samsung  G2 Portable           PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS
[  281.689380] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  281.689933] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
[  281.691012] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[  281.691014] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 3c 00 00 00
[  281.692120] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  281.716894]  sdc: sdc1
[  281.720114] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[  347.581801] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[  417.000613] usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  417.250145] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[  417.746108] usb 1-1.4: device not accepting address 5, error -71
[  492.889935]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2
```

It doesn't show up on the `fdisk` and it doesn't recognize the usb after the `dmesg`. I'm not really Linux savvy or know much about the information these commands printed out, therefore I'm looking for suggestions what to try next in bringing the HDD back from the dead. (Initial plan was just running "testdisk" on the HDD, but it's not recognized on the testdisk devices list either.

Comment: If it doesn't show up in both Windows and Ubuntu the disk is most likely dead (dead as in damaged to the point of unusability). I would try removing the USB controller and swapping it out for another.

Comment: So `sdb` is not the external drive, right? What about `sdc`?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto `sdb` is not external drive. About the `sdc`, I think I've messed up a bit. I've tried another (working) external hdd to check if the cable and usb port are working, so that might've triggered the `sdc` to show up in the message (since when I've tried swapping ports, the `mesg` kept only printing messages about the mouse I've replugged to other port, nothing about `sdc`). Other "problem" is, that when i go to /media/username/ directory and try to list the directories there, it doesn't show `sdb` either. Only when I access `sdb` through file manager - then it shows up on `ls`

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto, also, now trying the `mesg` command, it shows only about wireless network inferfaces, something about intel_rapl and other text I don't understand, but nothing about usb, drives or `sdx`, so I guess, now it's not even recognized as usb device or something like that? Thanks for help, anyways.

Comment: Your only option is to check if some other distro sees it. As weird as it may seem, I happened to get a drive recognized by an old build of Parted Magic (pre-2013) or similarly old distros while not with new ones. I don't really know why, maybe different kernels that played better with damaged drives.

If you cannot see the device, it's basically gone and you need a data recovery company.